# Laravel and Laragon from Windows to Linux

Tags: linux, laravel, laragon

Ok so I've been using Laragon 2.2.2 on Windows, and Laravel (the latest version I believe), and for now the whole thing was sitting in `C:\laragon\www\site`.
Now I need to move the site to a local host, on a Linux virtual machine (the virtual machine doesn't matter that much, just remember a 'Linux' system), and I'll probably use xampp, I've been told it's a good alternative to Laragon. I wanted to know if you got any suggestion on how I could process this system changing, without "breaking" anything.
By breaking, I mean that all the path I use in Controllers, for example, wouldn't work if I just change the root folder (I used sometimes the Laravel helper `storage_path()` or `public_path()`, and I don't really know if this is even a good way to use Laravel. Also when using the Storage, or all facades in general, I'm not sure if everything wuold still work.
I need to know how many things i need to modify to make the web site work after moving everything to a Linux system. I think about a file in config that contains a path that `storage_path()` would be loading, so we can easey edit this file and use all paths this way.... I'm not very experienced with Laravel, expecially when it's about paths.
Note: The web site does not contains any database related content, only files withing Laravel file system (in Storage, or public), views, templates, Laravel basic stuff.